# Converting stylus to less (css)

Tags: less, stylus

I have a project and using [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) for my css.

For reasons I don't want to go into right now, I want to switch to [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/).

I'd like to keep the file structure (imports and all), and also keep the color values what they are (`hsl`, `hsla`, `rgb`, etc) and not have them all convert to `#hex`.

I'd also like to keep any variables and macros I've defined ..

Of course, I prefer not to do it manually!!

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Lessify and http://css2less.cc won't be of any help as variables, imports and colors are lost, alas. Do you still have braces around block rules? Fluency in regexp and rewriting the reverse of this script https://gist.github.com/MoOx/3490671 may help you

Comment: FYI-"[Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: @ScottS The question is not about choosing a particular library. Anyway I rephrased the question, better now?

Comment: It was the finding of a "tool" not "library" that made me post the link. But your edit has removed that specific request. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW I think these silly rules are why SO is not so useful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this library while googling how we will upgrade to Angular 12:
https://github.com/txs1992/stylus-converter

Answer (score -1):

This page has several converters http://csspre.com/convert

If the Stylus to Less conversion doesn't yield the desired results you can try converting to Sass first and then to Less.

Comment: either the site has very bad UI or it's some kind of a nonsense .. I can't tell what's what in that table.

Comment: except you can't go from stylus to less